# Saving unsigned char * to file and reading it produces unexpected results in Windows

Tags: c++, input, output

The below code works fine in Ubuntu. I am loading a texture for openGL using glad and glfw.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"


const bool loadResavedImages = true;
GLFWwindow* window;

void loadTexture( char const *filename, unsigned int &texture )
{
    
    cout << filename << endl;
    
    //static int texturesLoaded = 0;
    glGenTextures( 1, &texture );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );
    
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    
    int width, height, nrChannels;
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load( true );
    
    unsigned char * data = NULL;
    
    char newFileName[ 50 ];
    snprintf( newFileName, sizeof(char) * ( strlen( filename ) - 3 ), "%s", filename );
    
    
    ifstream readFile( newFileName );
    
    if( loadResavedImages && readFile )
    {
        if( readFile.is_open() )
        {
            readFile >> width >> height;
            data = new unsigned char[ width * height * 4 ];
            readFile.read( (char *)data, width * height * 4 );
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "shouldnt happendfklgdskf" << endl;
        }
        
        readFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        readFile.close();
        
        data = stbi_load( filename, &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0 );
        //saved images
        
        //save to a file
        
        ofstream saveFile( newFileName );
        
        if( saveFile.is_open() )
        {
            saveFile << width << " " << height;
            saveFile.write( (char *)&data[ 0 ], width * height * 4 );
        }
        else
            cout << "WHY!?!?!SDSGGFGAGSSG" << endl;
        
        
        saveFile.close();
    }   
    
    for( int i = 0; i < width * height * 4; i++ )
    {
        cout << int( data[ i ] ) << " ";
    }
    
    if ( data )
    {
        glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data );
            
        glGenerateMipmap( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "failed to load texture " << filename <<endl;
        exit( 0 );
    }
    
    if( loadResavedImages && readFile )
        delete [] data;
    else
    {
        stbi_image_free( data );
    }
    
}




// main
int main()
{
    glfwInit();
        
    window = glfwCreateWindow( 500, 500, "Window", NULL, NULL );
    
    glfwMakeContextCurrent( window );
    
    if ( !gladLoadGLLoader( (GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress ) )
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    
    //load texture
    unsigned int texture;
    loadTexture( "twirl.png", texture );
    
    return 0;
}
```

When loading this 400x400 texture "twirl.png" on Ubuntu, which is mostly empty transparent space we get expectedly a bunch of 0s at the end.

If you save and reload this texture from the data file "twirl" it expectedly outputs the same thing on Ubuntu.

If this is run on windows the outputs at the end are different. We have an output of

```
205 205 205 205 205 205 205 205 205 205 205 205 205 205 205 205 205 205 205 205 205 205 205 205 205
```

... etc
instead of the expected empty space

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

etc..

Why does this occur on windows and how to get it to load and save correctly?

Comment: Recommendation: Open up the file in a hex editor and see what really made it into the file. Given single-line snippets we can't help you much better than a car mechanic can if you just give them the car's steering wheel. Too much context missing.

Comment: There is no "unsigned char * to char * conversion", it is just a pointer type-cast, the actual data is unaltered. Also, `(char *)&data[ 0 ]` can be simplified to `(char *)data`. In any case, please provide a [mcve] showing how you are allocating and filling `data`, `width` and `height` before saving/loading to/from the file. Writing `0`s to file and then reading them back as `205`s implies **undefined behavior** is at play somewhere in your code. Decimal `205` is hex `0xCD`, and a series of `0xCD` bytes is a common indicator of uninitialized memory being used, depending on your compiler config

Comment: On Windows you must open the file in binary mode to avoid line ending translation issues and premature EOF detection.

Comment: ok maybe I can make a minimal reproducible example

Comment: You are not being downvoted. The question is because it cannot be answered in its current state. This isn't because we're digital gods and you are not, it's a matter of providing good enough information about the problem for us to understand the problem. Definitely take Remy's advice and construct a [mre], but also consider recompiling your code on the ubuntu machine with `-fsanitize=address,undefined` on the command line. This should enable a bunch of extra checking for misbehaviour you might not yet have seen on the Ubuntu box.

Comment: ok understood. I thought I provided enough info but I guess I didn't

Comment: retired ninja answered this question. Things loaded correctly after doing binary mode

Comment: Recommendation: Even though your problem has been resolved, clean up the question and try to salvage it. The server, far as we can tell, never forgets and never forgives, a few years from now (and a few more poorly received questions) you may find this question contributing to a question ban. Deleting the question doesn't help. The server counts the deleted questions, too.

Comment: I think this question is valid as is and can be useful to people who have a similar issue on windows vs Ubuntu.. When I did 
 ifstream readFile( newFileName, ios_base::binary ); and ofstream saveFile( newFileName, ios_base::binary ); it fixed the issue. Before I didn't do binary and I had the issue.

Comment: @Brian It's not though. As you said opening the files in binary mode fixes the issue but that code isn't anywhere in your question, it was just a good guess based on a common mistake.

Comment: I'll add the readFile and saveFile load code to the question. I didn't know about binary mode

Comment: Brian, give the [mre] (MRE) link a good read through. It describes a process for making best-of-breed code examples. It's also a distillation of several very effective debugging techniques. If you start the question-asking process by isolating the problem in a MRE, you'll often find you're done with the question long before you start typing anything into Stack Overflow. Asking good questions is hard work, and usually the reward is not having to ask the question.

Comment: perhaps I could have phrased it better. is there a similar question out there on stack overflow? Thank you for the feedback

Comment: `ifstream readFile( newFileName );` maybe the file was not even opened so it read nothing at all. The output you show would be consistent with that in `msvc` meaning if your code failed to read I would expect the data to be exactly what you have received if you were running msvc in debug mode. The reason is what @RemyLebeau mentioned long ago. msvc fills heap memory with 0xcd in debug mode:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/what-are-the-debug-memory-fill-patterns-in-visual-studio-c-and-windows

Comment: I edited this using the minimum reproducible example as suggested. Let me know if I could make further changes so it becomes more clear.

Comment: The opening of the files in text mode is is likely part of the problem.

Comment: i dont know.. but for whatever reason using binary mode works

Comment: Question looks to be answerable now. Thank you. Hopefully more people return, vote to reopen, and remove the downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to automatic character translation when the file is opened in the default text mode, changing the two lines of code

```
ifstream readFile( newFileName );
//...
//...
ofstream saveFile( newFileName );
//...
```

to

```
ifstream readFile( newFileName, ios_base::binary );
//...
//...
ofstream saveFile( newFileName, ios_base::binary ); 
//...
```

fixes the issue in Windows.